# why Javafx standalone application accepting double click?

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, double-click

Here is my Main java file.The probelm is that the Whole project is working on double click when i launch it.

```
    public Stage primaryStage;
    public BorderPane rootLayout;
    private Pane splashLayout;
    private ProgressBar loadProgress;
    private Label progressText;
    private static final int SPLASH_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int SPLASH_HEIGHT = 400;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(final Stage initStage) throws Exception {
          //this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "KDAF_Splash.fxml"));
                try {
                   // flag = false;
                    Parent root2 = fxmlLoader1.load();

                     Stage stage2 = new Stage();
                    stage2.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
                 //   masterpane = new Pane();
                   // masterpane.setOpacity(1);
                   // stage2.setTitle("Create New Project");
                    stage2.setScene(new Scene(root2, 600, 400));
                    stage2.show();
                    PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
                    delay.setOnFinished( event ->{ stage2.close();showMainStage();} );

                    delay.play();

                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
                }

        };




    private void showMainStage(
    ) {
          try {
              // Load root layout from fxml file.
              FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
              loader.setLocation(Preloader.class.getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
              rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
              Stage stage=new Stage();
              stage.setTitle("Activation");
              Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
              //stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
              stage.setScene(scene);
              stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

              stage.show();
              showPersonOverview();
              //mainStage.show();
          /*    mainStage.setTitle("Activation Wizard");
              // Show the scene containing the root layout.
              Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
             // primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
              mainStage.setResizable(false);

              mainStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
              mainStage.setScene(scene);
              mainStage.show();
            showPersonOverview();*/

          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
    public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("activation wizard.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            personOverview.setPrefHeight(400);           
            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.



            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showSplash(
            final Stage initStage,
            Task<?> task,
            InitCompletionHandler initCompletionHandler
    ) {
        progressText.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
        loadProgress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        task.stateProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                loadProgress.progressProperty().unbind();
                loadProgress.setProgress(1);
                initStage.toFront();
                FadeTransition fadeSplash = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(1.2), splashLayout);
                fadeSplash.setFromValue(1.0);
                fadeSplash.setToValue(0.0);
                fadeSplash.setOnFinished(actionEvent -> initStage.hide());
                fadeSplash.play();

                initCompletionHandler.complete();
            } // todo add code to gracefully handle other task states.
        });

        Scene splashScene = new Scene(splashLayout);
        initStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        final Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        initStage.setScene(splashScene);
        initStage.setX(bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2 - SPLASH_WIDTH / 2);
        initStage.setY(bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2 - SPLASH_HEIGHT / 2);
        initStage.show();
    }

    public interface InitCompletionHandler {
        public void complete();
    }
     }
```

The FXml is given below. Please help me to resolve this issue. If the question is not clear help me to explain better. The main problem is when the application is launched after splash screen. The button accepts double click and then moves to load next FXML. this is been very painful as i have to double click everytime instead of single click. I am not able to identify the problem here. Whether it is a problem that persists from scene builder or the problem is in the main preloader class.Even the menu item is accepting double click. I try to google the solution for but could not find any solution. please look int the code and help to resolve this issue. I have done a lot of R&D but all went vain . There might be a little problem in it but i am not being able to identify it. Please ignore the formatting of code and unused variables. The code is not final yet. finally i would like to remind the main problem is that after launching, the application  is working only on double click. lets look at the work flow to understand it better. SPLASH SCREEN->ACTIVATION WIZARD-*DOUBLE CLICK ON A BUTTON*->TIP SCREEN-*DOUBLE CLICK ON A BUTTON*->PROJECT SCREEN->DOUBLE CLICK TO OPEN ANYTHING. It is really frustrating. please help.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-border-color: black;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="EventHandlingController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="301.0" layoutY="333.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Buy Full Version" />
      <Button fx:id="myButton7" layoutX="420.0" layoutY="333.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Showtip" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="Continue Trial " />
      <TextField editable="false" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="108.0" prefHeight="151.0" prefWidth="449.0" style="-fx-background-color: silver;" text="You have &lt;xx&gt; days left on your trial.">
         <font>
            <Font size="21.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <Label layoutX="85.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="135.0" text="Activation Wizard">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="closebutt" layoutX="573.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closebuttonD" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="20.0" text="X" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: So, you always have to make a double click instead of a single click (as usual)?

Comment: YEAh...problem resolved though....MouseEvent should also be used with on action. otherwise it will always accept double click

Comment: The probelem was due to the Action event. Instead of passing ActionEvent the MouseEvent should be used.